# Zend Framework set on bootstrap.php custom locale

Tags: zend-framework, zend-locale

how to set custom locale in zend framework by create a function in bootstrap file? I need to change error messege in zend form.

Thanks for support

Comment: Exactly what I need!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to set the locale

```
// within your bootstrap
$locale = new Zend_Locale('de_AT');
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);

// within your model or controller
$date = new Zend_Date();
print $date->getLocale();
echo $date->getDate();
```

More info on the [Zend_Locale](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.locale.introduction.html#zend.locale.frameworkwidelocale)

For adding translated error message to the form validators you have to add them to the `Zend_Validate_Abstract`

> From the ZF manual
>
> Zend Framework is shipped with more than 45 different validators with
>   more than 200 failure messages. It can be a tedious task to translate
>   all of these messages. But for your convenience Zend Framework comes
>   with already pre-translated validation messages. You can find them
>   within the path /resources/languages in your Zend Framework
>   installation. So to translate all validation messages to German for
>   example, all you have to do is to attach a translator to Zend_Validate
>   using these resource files.

```
 $translator = new Zend_Translate(
      'array',
      '/resources/languages',
      $language,
      array('scan' => Zend_Locale::LOCALE_DIRECTORY)
  );
  Zend_Validate_Abstract::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

More info on the validator error message is in their manual [Using pre-translated validation messages](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.messages.html#zend.validate.messages.pretranslated)

I havent personally used the translation adaptors, but from the manual [Creating CSV source files for Translation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.sourcecreation.html#zend.translate.sourcecreation.csv) it seems the below code will add the `translator` to the application

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
    array(
        'adapter' => 'csv',
        'content' => '/path/to/mytranslation.csv',
        'locale'  => 'de'
    )
);
```

Also a sample of the .csv format

> message1;Nachricht1
>   message2;Nachricht2

Comment: this setting in which function of bootstrap i have to put?

Comment: I tryed but i get this error: `Error including array or file '/resources/languages'`

Comment: I don't need to add my personal translation, but i want to use the default italian translation, present in zend Library -> Locale -> Data -> it.xml